# how to save and replace multiple string in specific Array index

Tags: java, arrays, string

I try to save multiple strings in Array by using ,

> myStringArray[0] = String

, but it keep saying

> array type expected found java.lang.string

than I use

> myStringArray.add(0,String)

it works , but can not replace specific index , it append more and more string in this array

than I try

> myStringArray.set(0, String)

throw error at begging , cause index[0] in empty

than I though

> for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i ++){ myStringArray[i]=i; } at begging than use myArray.set()

and it come back the first issue

help please

code

```
private String imageLocation;
imageLocation = image.getAbsolutePath();

ArrayList<String> imagesLocations = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (cameraOption == 0){
        imageButtonOne.setImageBitmap(resizePhoto);
        imagesLocations.add(0,imageLocation);
        }
    if (cameraOption == 1){
        imageButtonTwo.setImageBitmap(resizePhoto);
        imagesLocations.remove(1);
        imagesLocations.set(1,imageLocation);
         }
```

Comment: How did you declare `myStringArray`?

Comment: @bradimus hi! I just update the code , please check :)

Comment: The posted code does not show the declaration of `myArrayString`. Please always post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of `imagesLocations` (which I assume is supposed to line up with `myStringArray`)

```
ArrayList<String> imagesLocations = new ArrayList<String>();
```

makes it an `ArrayList<>`, not an array of `String`. That would have been

```
String[] imagesLocations = new String[someArraySize];
```

You should probably review the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) for `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thank you ! you are right! :D 
sorry , just start coding , thank you again!